# Sacar cantidad de un bucle do-while

Tags: java

Hola, necesito ayuda para extraer la información de una variable de un bucle do-while y llevarla al main mediante un return para posteriormente usarla en otro método. El problema es que no sé como poner la variable contadora para sacar los datos.
Quiero sacar la cantidad de `intentos` en el total de las partidas que juego y luego quiero saber la partida con menos intentos para acertar, pero ahí si que no sé como hacerlo.
Aquí mi código:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Acierta {
   static int jugadas;
   static int acertadas;
   
   public static final int INTENTOS = 10;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
   
   Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in); 
     
  
   int intentos = partida(teclado);   
   String rep = otra(teclado);   
   while (rep.startsWith("s")) {
      intentos = partida(teclado);  
      rep = otra(teclado);               
   }    
   estadisticas(intentos);
   }   
   
   public static int partida(Scanner teclado) {
      Random rand = new Random(20);
      int numIntro = 0;
      int intentos = 0;         
      int numR = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;   
      System.out.println("Adivina un número del 1 al 100"); 
      jugadas++;  
      do {        
         System.out.println("Adivina el número: ");
         numIntro = teclado.nextInt(); 
         intentos++;     
         if (numIntro < numR) {
            System.out.println("El número es mayor.");
         } else if (numIntro > numR) {
            System.out.println("El número es menor.");
         }             
      } while (numIntro != numR && intentos < INTENTOS);      
      if (numIntro == numR) { 
         System.out.println("Has adivinado en " + intentos + " intentos.");          
         acertadas++; 
      } else {
         System.out.println("No has adivinado el número secreto: " + numR);
      }
      intentos += intentos;       
      return intentos; 
   }
   public static String otra(Scanner teclado) {
         System.out.println("¿Quieres jugar otra vez (S/N)? ");
         String rep = teclado.next().toLowerCase();
         return rep;      
   }
   public static void estadisticas(int intentos) {
      System.out.println("Resultados:");
      System.out.println("Jugadas: " + jugadas);
      System.out.println("Intentos: " + intentos);
      System.out.println("Acertadas: " + acertadas);
      double intentosP = intentos / jugadas;
      System.out.println("Intentos por partida: " + intentosP);       
      System.out.println("Mejor: ");
   }
}
```

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: como no sabes cuantas veces se volverá a jugar podrías usar un ArrayList donde almacenes los intentos en cada partida, lo otro es que según tu código en el primer juego se generara un dato aleatorio el cual seguirá siendo el mismo si se elije jugar otra vez,debes considerar ese detalle ;)

Comment: @Dramaturgo, alguna opción más sencilla que un array(todavía no lo hemos dado) en cuanto a que el número aleatorio se repita estoy al tanto, solo quiero conseguir el número de intentos totales y además la partida en la que menos intentos se han hecho hasta acertar.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes guardarla en una lista o usar un acumulador, según necesites simplemente el número total o el número de cada partida para todas las jugadas:

```java
List<Integer> todosLosIntentos = new ArrayList<>(); //una opción
int totalIntentos = 0; //otra opción
int partidasJugadas = 0;
boolean seguir = true;

while (seguir) {
    int intentos = partida(teclado);
    todosLosIntentos.add(intentos);
    totalIntentos += intentos; 
    partidasJugadas++;
    String rep = otra(teclado);
    seguir = rep.startsWith("s");                 
}
   todosLosIntentos.forEach(intentos -> estadisticas(intentos));
```

Comment: Supongo que está bien, pero al no haberlo dado no podría usarlo. Gracias de todas formas.

Comment: Te pongo las dos opciones, con una lista o simplemente con un acumulador

Comment: El acumulador es lo que necesito, pero no sé dónde colocarlo para que me cuente todos los intentos de todas las partidas que juego, y sigo sin saber como obtener el dato de la partida en la que menos intentos se necesitan.

Comment: Crea una variable `minimosIntentos` y en cada iteración comprueba si el número de intentos es menor que el valor actual.